# If $(A'|b')$ is obtained from $(A|b)$ by a finite sequence of elementary column operations, then the systems $Ax = b$ and $A'x = b'$ are equivalent.

Tags: linear-algebra

The claim is:

"If $(A'|b')$ is obtained from $(A|b)$ by a finite sequence of elementary column operations, then the systems $Ax = b$ and $A'x = b'$ are equivalent."

It has already been shown that this is true for elementary row operations. From all that I've read I was under the guise that elementary row operations are equivalent to elementary column operations. As such if I did column operations I thought the same statement would stand, but apparently it doesn't. Why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the linear system $ax = 1$, which has solution $\frac{1}{a}$. Now apply an elementary column operation, scaling one of the columns by $2$ to get $2ax = 1$, which has solution $\frac{1}{2a}$, which is not the same as $\frac{1}{a}$. On the other hand, scaling the only row by $2$ to get $2ax = 2$ does not change the solution. Is this enough of a counterexample?

Comment: Yes it is. Thanks for your help. Makes sense now.